# Get the value of a stored procedure and pass that as a parameter to another stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I need to get the value of this stored procedure and pass it as a parameter to another stored procedure.

```
SqlCommand GetName = new SqlCommand("usp_GetName", sqlcon);
GetName.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
GetName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@printer", printerguid);
```

This stored procedure has a simple select statement that returns only one row at any given point. I need to get that data and pass tat as a parameter elsewhere... Please tell me how to get the value from this stored procedure and store it in a variable

Comment: How many values does the procedure return and how many values do you need to store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it only returns one value use this and cast it to the type it is (`string`, `int`, etc)

```
var returnedValue = GetName.ExecuteScalar();
```

If you have more than 1 fields you should use:

```
using(IDataReader reader = GetName.ExecuteReader())
{
  if (reader.Read())
  {
    // Populate any object using reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FieldName"))
    // Replace GetString for any data type you need.
  }
  else
  {
    // No rows returnes
  }
}
```